# How to get a list of all top apps on play store

Tags: google-play, web-crawler

I need a way to get a list of all top apps from google **play-store**.

for example:

Top Free apps has 540 ranked apps from 1 to 540: [Example - Top Free Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free)

The Problem is that when I opening the page programmatically (php,or others) I get only **60** top apps.

Is there a way to bypass google "show more" button and get all 540 top free apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Look at what the page is doing in a live AJAX viewer such as Firebug. The required start point and count are submitted as post parameters, and an HTML result is returned. You may have to do this in pieces, but try it in one call to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it (Thanks to @halfer)
We need to do a POST to google play url:

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free**

And we need to send this parms with it:

`start=0` <-- Start from 0;

`num=60` <-- Give back 60 apps

`numChildren=0` <-- I have no idea

`ipf=1` <-- It seems to have a connection with the header

`xhr=1` <-- page format

**If we want app from 60 to 120 we need to request it like this:**
`start=60&num=120`

Comment: Thanks, it seems like there is a limit to number of apps shown and this appears to depend on which collection you are querying.
I would like to eventually scrape all apps, do you know if there a way to get around this?

Comment: I thinks this is the only way to get the data from the apps.
another way is to do this:
Go to Google and search this: **`site:"https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id="`**
It will give you the list of all apps available on PLAY.

Comment: I was getting the collections and from there a list of developers that I would crawl. But I think your suggestion is much more comprehensive. Thanks, really nice suggestion.

Comment: btw.. I think there is a search API.. so you can get the list faster

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot. I'm only interested in games though there's a bit of work involved when I scrape each page I'll have to check the "app's" genre falls into one of the game genres.

Comment: @ofear Why it doesn't work for https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/COMMUNICATION/collection/topselling_free?start=600&num=25

Comment: I am stuck with this one. Weirdly https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/COMMUNICATION/collection/topselling_free?start=500&num=120 show 500-620 apps but 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/COMMUNICATION/collection/topselling_free?start=500&num=121 fails and show 1-5 apps. Are you able to get the list of top apps. Also even if we scroll play store only shows 540 apps in each category. WEIRD!

Answer (score 2):

I have did the job in Python before, what you need is a web auto test lib called selenium, it can execute Javascript code and return the result to Python, with Javascript, you can click the "show more" button by the program itself. The simple demo [here](https://github.com/aswekown/simple-demo-spider-for-google-play) .Hope helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can just access: https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/YOUR-CATEGORY/collection/YOUR-COLLECTION?start=0&num=10

```
$num = 10
$start =0;
while($start<540){
  // TODO: your request for get data
  $start=$start+10;
}
```

It's longer but it works

Comment: It seems like Google has removed the top apps per category, therefore this answer does no longer work.